# Compiler error with templates and boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm creating a small thread management object to use to start threads (for now) in a more generic fashion in my programs. It is template based and I am using boost threads as the underlying thread "engine". I intend to use this as a cross platform wrapper to replace some legacy code that I am porting to linux.

The basic implementation of my code looks something like this:

```
using mythread = boost::thread; 

class ThreadManager
{
public:
    ThreadManager();
    ~ThreadManager() {}

    template<class _Fn, class... _Args>
    mythread* CreateThreadPtr(unsigned int Priority, ::std::string& name, unsigned int stackSz, _Fn&& func, _Args&&... args)
    {
        //boost::thread::attributes attrs;
        //attrs.set_stack_size(1024);
        //boost::thread t{attrs, thread};

        mythread* T = new mythread(func, args...);
        void* hndl = (void*)T->native_handle();
        if (hndl)
        {
            #ifdef WIN32
            BOOL res = SetThreadPriority(hndl, Priority);
            if (!res)
            {
                //dwError = GetLastError();
            }
            #else

            //TODO

            #endif

            SetThreadName(T, name);

            return T;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    void SetThreadName(THANDLE thread, ::std::string& threadName);
#ifdef WIN32
    void SetThreadName(THREAD_ID threadId, ::std::string& threadName);
#endif
#ifdef __linux__
    void SetThreadName(void* hThread, ::std::string& threadName);
#endif

    THREAD_ID GetThreadId();
};

ThreadManager& Man(void);
```

Which will be used like this:

```
m_TxRxThread = Man().CreateThreadPtr(Priority, thread_name, 0,ThreadProcTxRx, this);
```

But when I build it I get this error

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:253:35: error: invalid conversion from 'CEth*' to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
```

With `-fpermissive` everything seems to work fine, but this makes no sense to me and I want to know what I am doing wrong here!

Thanks in advance!

-- Edit --

`ThreadProcTxRx` is a method of a `CEth` object whose signature is

```
void CEth::ThreadProcTxRx(ul32 lpParam)
```

where `ul32` is `typedef unsigned long`...

And by writing this last sentence the proverbial light bulb light up... Of course that this needs to be a `ul32. I was focusing on`ThreadProcTxRx`when the error pointed to`this`.

Well... Thanks to Praetorian for asking for clarification. If you want to put that in an answer I'll credit you for that.

Comment: What is `ThreadProcTxRx`? Looks like it expects an `unsigned long` argument, but you're passing it a pointer to `CEth`. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> -fpermissive
>
> Downgrade some diagnostics about nonconformant code from errors to warnings. Thus, using -fpermissive will allow some nonconforming code to compile.

By compiling with `-fpermissive` you are downgrading some errors with your code to warning to compile. You should avoid doing this.

What's happing with your code is you're trying to assign an `unsigned long` with a type of `CEth*`. You will need to `static_cast` your return to an `unsigned long` if possible or check your return types are correct.